# How to get duplicate error

Tags: php

I just want to have a duplicate error when my program is running.

I made a condition that if the user had already enrolled a student (with matched `studId` and `sy`), it gives me an error like "You already did the enrollment." else, it would do the insert query. In my table I inserted a `studId(c-1111)` & `sy(2011)` just for instance that there is a old student is/are being enrolled, but on my situation when I click my button "Generate & save", it always give me the error message even the `sy` is 2013 with the same `studId` of c-1111. Here's my code. Please help me solve my program.

```
       for($i=0; $i <= $row->studId; $i++){           
        $generated_pass = genpass($i);
        echo "<td>$generated_pass</td>";
        $year = date("Y");
        $info = $mysqli->query("SELECT studId, sy FROM tbl_student WHERE
                    studId='".$row->studId."' AND sy= '$year'");
        if($info){
            echo "<script type='text/jscript'>
        alert('You already did the enrollment.')
        window.location='admin.php';</script>";
            }
        else {
        $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO  tbl_student (studId,
                    fname,  lname, mname, password, dob, address, f_fname, f_mname,
                    f_lname, m_fname, m_mname, m_lname, departmentId, sy) VALUES 
                    ('".$row->studId."', '".$row->fname."', '".$row->lname."', 
                    '".$row->mname."', '".md5($generated_pass)."', '".$row->dob."', 
                    '".$row->address."', '".$row->f_fname."', '".$row->f_mname."', 
                    '".$row->f_lname."', '".$row->m_fname."', '".$row->m_mname."', 
                    '".$row->m_lname."', '".$row->departmentId."', '".$row->sy."')");
                }
                    }
```

Comment: Please Debug what $info = $mysqli->query("SELECT studId, sy FROM tbl_student WHERE studId='".$row->studId."' AND sy= '$year'");

Answer (score 0):

is it an option to add a MySQL table constraint that studID and sy are a unique key? that way, any query that inserts a duplicate will fail, and PHP will get an error it can handle.

Edit: the IGNORE keyword should be removed for the above to work, since it essentially requests that constraints are not honored. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: @hexblot.. yeah i forgot to remove the IGNORE, but even i remove it my insert query still not working. and yes, my studId is a primary key. i thought of a function but i only know about like just in an input type eg emails on registration.

Answer (score 0):

Please Debug what

```
$info = $mysqli->query("SELECT studId, sy FROM tbl_student WHERE studId='".$row->studId."' AND sy= '$year'");
```

and $info returns.
It might be it will be return empty array in that case ur if($info) wont work then you need to check with `empty()` etc